# How do i access an array inside an object of an array?

Tags: reactjs

How do i access the sub_categories array in an array of input?

```
const input = [{
    "id": 3252,
    "title": "Payment",
    "sub_categories": [{
      "id": 3252,
      "subtitle": "House",
    }],
}]
```

Example output:

```
const output = [{
      "id": 3252,
      "subtitle": "House",
}]
```

Comment: Directly (in poor form): `input[0].sub_categories` or `input[0]["sub_categories"]`. It may be better to have these parsed/serialized into some known type ahead of time, depending on your codebase/languages in use. For example, the overall object within the array could be one type, with a pseudo-code `Category[]` array that is additionally parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one object in the array like your example you can just use the

`const output = input[0].sub_categories`

But if you have an array with more than one object like below, you can use a for loop and print the output like this.

```
const input = [{
    "id": 3252,
    "title": "Payment",
    "sub_categories": [{
      "id": 3252,
      "subtitle": "House",
    }]},
   { "id": 3253,
    "title": "Payment",
    "sub_categories": [{
      "id": 3253,
      "subtitle": "House1",
    }],
}]

for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
  console.log(input[i].sub_categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use find, includes and map methods to achieve that

```
let id = 3252;
const result = input.find(i => i.sub_categories.map(s => s.id).includes(id)).sub_categories
```

Output:

```
Array [Object { id: 3252, subtitle: "House" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(input[0]["sub_categories"]);
```

Output:

```
[{
  id: 3252,
  subtitle: "House"
}]
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use .sub_categories on the object reference to get the field in the object with that name. So to get the subcategories of the first object in the input array would look like  this:

```
const input = [{
    "id": 3252,
    "title": "Payment",
    "sub_categories": [{
      "id": 3252,
      "subtitle": "House",
    }],
}]

/// Use input[0] to get the first array item 
/// Then use .sub-categories to get the array inside the object.

const output = input[0].sub_categories
```

Answer (score -1):

Map the input into subcateogies and flatten it to receive an array of all subcategories.

```js
input.map(input => input.sub_categories).flat()
```